# Language problem of presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations, turkish

I try to give my presentation in Turkish:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\title{Title}
\author{İÖÇığş}
\institute{University}
\date{2020}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
Turkish Pangram: Pijamalı hasta yağız şoföre çabucak güvendi.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But Overleaf gives me warnings below:

```
Package hyperref main.tex, line 16
Warning:Composite letter
'\textdotaccent+I' not defined in PD1 encoding, removing '\textdotaccent' on input line 16.

Package hyperref main.tex, line 16
Warning:Glyph not defined in PD1
encoding, removing '\u' on input line 16. 

Package hyperred main.tex, line 16
Warning:Composite letter '\textcedilla+s' 
not defined in PD1 encoding, removing '\textcedilla' on input line 16.
```

Since I added `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` then why it gives me those messages?

Comment: I guess you're using pdfLaTeX to compile the document. Do you still get warnings if you switch to LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure since it's on Overleaf. Because Overleaf doesn't show what it is.

Comment: Just fyi you can change the compiler in Overleaf, but if I recall correctly it's a global setting (as opposed to locally, per-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `unicode` option to `hyperref` and the warnings will disappear.

```latex
\documentclass[hyperref=unicode]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\title{Title}
\author{İÖÇığş}
\institute{University}
\date{2020}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
Turkish Pangram: Pijamalı hasta yağız şoföre çabucak güvendi.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```